# Expressão Regular para clonar um valor em um campo

Tags: regex

Tenho os seguintes valores:

```
PRO|00000001|GASOLINA ADITIVADA|0101001|27101259|
```

Gostaria de uma expressão que mudasse os valores e ficassem assim:

```
PRO|00000001|GASOLINA ADITIVADA|00000001|27101259|
```

Eu já tenho mais ou menos uma ideia de como será:

```
(^PRO\|)(\d*)(.\w*.)
```

Mas o problema é que ela só ta pegando até:

```
PRO|00000001|GASOLINA
```

E não estou conseguindo pegar o valor restante do `ADITIVADA|`.

Comment: Sempre vai ter "PRO" e "GASOLINA ADITIVADA" ou pode ter outros textos? Que linguagem vc está usando?

Comment: vai ter outros textos, PRO é nome de produto, sempre vai ser PRO.. agora GASOLINA ADITIVADA é um exemplo.. poderia ser LUB SELENIA API SN15W40 SEMI-SINT1L

Answer (score 3):

*Eu acho mais fácil você fazer um `split`, separando os campos por `|` e em seguida concatenando o que você precisa, mas se quer usar regex, vamos lá.*

---

Se as suas entradas sempre são separadas por `|` e estão sempre nesta ordem, você pode ser mais específico, [dizendo exatamente o que quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want).

Se você só quer as linhas que começam com "PRO" e possuem "GASOLINA ADITIVADA", pode usar estes textos explicitamente. Senão, você pode usar `[^|]`, que significa "qualquer coisa que não seja `|`".

Usar o ponto (`.`) é abrangente demais, pois significa "qualquer caractere". Usando explicitamente `|` para o separador dos campos e `[^|]` para "qualquer coisa que não seja o separador", a regex fica mais específica para o seu caso.

Outro detalhe é decidir se vai usar `+` em vez de `*`. Isso porque `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, se não tiver nada, também é válido. Já o `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, o campo não pode ser vazio.

O mesmo vale para os números, pois `\d*` vai aceitar o campo vazio. O melhor é usar `\d+`, que verifica se tem pelo menos um dígito. Ou, se você sabe a quantidade exata, use por exemplo `\d{8}` para exatamente 8 dígitos, ou `\d{8,}` para "8 ou mais dígitos" ou ainda `\d{8,20}` para "entre 8 e 20 dígitos". Escolha o que se encaixar melhor nos seus casos de uso e adapte as quantidades de acordo com o que você precisa.

Enfim, uma opção de regex seria:

```
^PRO\|\d+\|[^|]+\|\d+\|.*$
```

Repare que o `|` deve ser escapado e escrito como `\|`, já que somente um `|` significa alternância (ou seja, `PRO|\d+` significa "PRO" **ou** dígitos). Com isso temos:

- `^PRO\|`: começa com "PRO", seguido de `|`
- `\d+\|`: dígitos, seguido de `|`
- `[^|]+\|`: um ou mais caracteres que não são `|`, seguido de `|`
- `\d+\|`: dígitos, seguido de `|`
- `.*$`: zero ou mais caracteres, até o final da string (`$`)

Já para fazer a substituição, depende da linguagem que você está usando, pois cada uma tem suas próprias funções para substituição de strings com regex.

De qualquer forma, para isso geralmente usam-se parênteses para agrupar as partes que você quer capturar, então a regex ficaria assim:

```
^(PRO\|)(\d+\|)([^|]+\|)\d+\|(.*)$
```

O primeiro par de parênteses é `(PRO\|)`, então este será o primeiro grupo, o segundo par de parênteses é `(\d+\|)` (os dígitos mais o `|`), então este será o segundo grupo e assim por diante.

Para fazer a substituição, você usa a sintaxe `$1` para se referir ao primeiro grupo, `$2` para o segundo etc. Dependendo da linguagem/engine, a sintaxe é `\1`, `\2`, etc. Sendo assim, o resultado seria `$1$2$3$2$4` (o grupo 2 se repete no lugar do quarto campo). [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/pYGuof/3) um exemplo.